# Going in and out of a Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a large multi-dimensional array that looks like this (date values are year-month-day):

```
$current_branch = array(
            array('2014-05-26',100,17600,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-05-27',100,17600,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-05-28',100,17600,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-05-29',100,16600,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-05-30',100,17600,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-05-31',100,17600,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-06-02',100,12000,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-06-03',100,12000,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-06-04',100,12000,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-06-05',100,12000,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-06-07',100,12000,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-06-08',100,100,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-06-09',100,12000,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-06-10',100,12000,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-07-01',100,11000,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-07-02',100,14000,20600,3000,120,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-07-03',90,12000,20300,3000,140,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-07-04',90,12000,20300,3000,140,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-07-05',90,12000,20300,3000,140,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-07-06',80,11000,19300,3000,140,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2014-07-07',130,11000,19300,3000,140,15000,20000, 2000),
            array('2014-07-08',130,11000,19300,3000,140,15000,20000, 2000),
            array('2014-07-09',120,10000,19200,3100,140,16000,21000, 2000),
            array('2015-05-01',100,17600,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-05-02',100,17600,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-05-03',100,17600,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-05-04',100,17600,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-05-05',100,17600,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-06-01',100,17200,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-06-02',100,17300,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-06-03',100,17400,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-06-04',100,17500,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-06-06',100,17700,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-06-07',100,17800,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-06-08',100,17600,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-06-09',100,17600,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-06-10',100,17600,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-06-20',100,17600,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-06-30',144,14600,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-07-01',144,11600,17600,2000,80,13000,12000, 5000),
            array('2015-07-02',144,14600,20600,3000,80,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-07-03',154,15600,21600,4000,90,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-07-04',154,15600,21600,4000,90,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-07-05',154,15600,21600,4000,90,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-07-06',124,13600,20600,4000,90,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-07-07',124,2600,600,28000,90,15000,18000, 2000),
            array('2015-07-08',124,2300,21600,3000,90,14000,19000, 2100),
            array('2015-07-09',124,2800,21600,4100,90,15000,18000, 2000)
            );
```

As you can see, some dates and such are missing. Now, the array indexes *have* to be numeric for what I'm doing unfortunately (using results from a predefined soap server) but that's fine because a mental note can be made of what the values are, and they are; sale date, quantity sold in cash, cash net of that day, etc...

What I'd like to know is how can I manipulate that huge array in order to grab the total net value of the months in there (for examples sake lets say the 3rd value is the net for that day), and output them to an array that looks like this:

```
$data = array(
  array('jan', $jan_month_net), array('feb', $feb_month_net), 
  array('mar', $mar_month_net), array('apr', ...), 
  array('may', ...), array('jun', ...), 
  array('jul', ...), array('aug', ...), 
  array('sept', ...), array('oct', ...), 
  array('nov', ...),  array('dec', ...)
);
```

I've tried using a foreach:

```
$this_year_value = 2015;
$i=01;
foreach ($current_branch as $key => $value) {
    $i_padded = sprintf("%02d", $i); // so 01, 02, 03, etc
    $month_comparison = $this_year_value."-".$i_padded;
    $cut_soap_date = substr($value[0],0,7); // try to get 2015-MONTH
    if ($cut_soap_date == $month_comparison) { 
        $year_chart_data =  array($i_padded, $value[2]);
    }
$i++; 
}
```

This code had a fundamental flaw because the $i would increment at every foreach, essentially never providing a correct comparison to the current foreach month pointer. This is where I'm short on ideas, if any could be provided that'd be fantastic.

Comment: The arrage data doesn't *have* to be in a numeric array just because that's how the SOAP service provides it to you. Once it arrives in your program, you are free to change the formatting as much as you like to suit your own program.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that info, could be handy at some time! I think I'll leave it as it is now though, since I've become accustomed to it haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this_year_value = 2015;

// Make array before
$data = array(
  array('jan', 0), array('feb', 0), 
  array('mar', 0), array('apr', 0), 
  array('may', 0), array('jun', 0), 
  array('jul', 0), array('aug', 0), 
  array('sept', 0), array('oct', 0), 
  array('nov', 0),  array('dec', 0)
);

// fill array 
foreach ($current_branch as $key => $value) {
    // take second part of date
    $month_comparison = explode('-', $value[0])[1];
    $cut_soap_date = substr($value[0],0,7); // try to get 2015-MONTH
    if ($cut_soap_date == $this_year_value."-".$month_comparison) { 
        // write to result array
        $data[$month_comparison-1][1] += $value[2];
    }
}

var_export($data);
```

Comment: Ohh I see! I didn't even consider using explode, this is extremely helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about only incrementing $i if the dates do NOT match

```
if ($cut_soap_date == $month_comparison) { 
    $year_chart_data =  array($i_padded, $value[2]);
} else {
    $i++; 
}
```

Comment: The `$cut_soap_date` could start from any number (i.e. if the array passed to me only has months june to november it would be 06 for june and so on). Therefore, the `$i` continues to iterate without a match.

Comment: I'm thinking it needs to somehow find out it's at the same month as the cut_soap_date, and stay with it until the cut_soap_date moves onto the next month, but how would that practically be done?